# custom attribute display frontend error in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1

i have created custom attribute for ex. color in magento 2.1 but i can't able to display it in product view page frontend. so please guide me how to achieve this in the new version.

getAttributeText('color') this works in Magento 2.0.1 to Magento 2.0.7 but not working in Magento 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

In product view or product details page you can display like this.

..............................

```
$attribute = $this->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
if ($attribute)
{
    $color_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($this->getProduct());
}
```